# Azure mobile service Script save geography from lat long

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to save a geography data type from latitude and longitude. My script is:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {

    var incidentesTable = tables.getTable('incidentes');
    var detallesTable = tables.getTable('detalle_incidente');
    var point = "geography::STPointFromText('POINT(" + item.latitud.substring
        + " " + item.longitud.substring +")', 4326)";
        console.log(point);
    var items = {
        descripcion: item.descripcion,
        image: item.image,
        fecha: item.fecha,
        latitud: item.latitud,
        longitud: item.longitud,
        violencia: item.violencia,
        geopoint: point
    }

    incidentesTable.insert(items, {
        success: function()
        {
            var detalle = {incidente_id: items.id}; 
            detallesTable.insert(detalle, {
                success: function(){
                    request.respond(statusCodes.OK, {id: items.id});
                }
            })

        }
    }); 
}
```

Logging the point variable, its value is:

```
geography::STPointFromText('POINT(-33.5359 -70.7802)', 4326)
```

Seems fine, but it's not working, its raising an error:

```
Error in script '/table/incidentes.insert.js'. Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography":
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to construct the whole INSERT statement by hand. I found an example [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Geolocation-sample-end-to-5d9ee245). From that post:

```
function insert(item, user, request) { 
    var queryString = "INSERT INTO Place (title, description, location) VALUES (?, ?, geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + ? + ' '
+ ? + ')', 4326))";         
    mssql.query(queryString, [item.title, item.description, item.longitude.toString(), item.latitude.toString()], { 
                success: function() { 
                     request.respond(statusCodes.OK, {}); 
                } 
          });
}
```

**Edit 2**:
Note that you have latitude and longitude backwards; the "Well-Known Text" format that SQL Server uses has longitude first.

**Edit**:
Also, the error message you quoted had the full exception starting on the next line. If you have errors constructing the SQL statement, try doing the SQL in SSMS or equivalent to get the full error. Here's an example:

```
[SQL Server]A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography":  
System.FormatException: 24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees. System.FormatException:
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GeographyValidator.ValidatePoint(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.Validator.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.ForwardingGeoDataSink.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.CoordinateReversingGeoDataSink.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParsePointText(Boolean parseParentheses)
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType type)
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid)
 at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)
.
```